# SQL: Get All Sets of Dates Up to 20 Days Apart

Tags: sql, pentaho

I'm having trouble formulating a SQL query which, from a column containing dates, returns all sets of dates which are up to 20 days apart from each other.

So if, for instance, the dates are

```
1/1/2000, 1/15/2000, 1/20/2000, 2/1/2000
```

the sets would be:

```
{(1/1/2000, 1/15/2000, 1/20/2000), (1/15/2000, 1/20/2000, 2/1/2000)}
```

I want only the biggest sets possible: e.g (1/1/2000, 1/15/2000) is not included because it would be a subset of another set.

I suspect the answer would use a cross join.

Comment: tag the dbms you're using and post the expected result as formatted text.

Comment: (1) What database are you using (tag accordingly)?  (2) What doesthe output look like?  SQL queries return result sets, with a fixed number of columns.

Comment: If you look at biggest set, then the result is one set {1/1/2000, 1/15/2000, 1/20/2000, 2/1/2000}.

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL would look something like this:

```
select t.date as SetIdentifier, t2.date as date
from t join
     t t2
     on t2.date >= t.date and t2.date < t.date + interval '21 day'
order by t.date, t2.date;
```

This identifies each set by the first day in the set (assuming that all the dates are unique).